# Why is my Google App Engine deployment failing with a 404?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-webflux

I currently have the below configs for my Reactive Spring Boot app being hosted on Google App Engine (service name changed):

myservice:

```
runtime: java17
service: myservice
instance_class: B2
```

dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "myservice-dot-my-apps.ew.r.appspot.com/*"
    service: myservice

  - url: "*/*"
    service: default
```

I am trying to reach my service via the url `https://myservice-dot-my-apps.ew.r.appspot.com/c2b/customerpaybill/validate`, but all requests are being handled by the default service and thus am getting a 404, yet the routes were working before. This has began just after deploying a new version of `myservice`, and updating my payment details after a few hours of downtime due to payment issues. Anyone with an idea why the routes are now failing? I have tried downgrading the cloud SDK version in my maven.xml, but still no effect.